# Always getting error 400 when uploading image using graphQL and apollo server 4

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, graphql, apollo-server

I am trying to build a profile page for my new project where I require users to enter their data and that includes their profile picture also. I am using react in the frontend and node as the backend. I am using graphQL with apollo server 4 to handle the requests. Accordingly I am using apollo client 3 in the frontend. I am using mongodb to save the data. The image file will be saved in the mongodb as well. The problem is in whatever way I tried to upload my image file by hitting the addProfile mutation, I always ends up getting error 400.
[graphql error 400](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCpux.png)

How should i modify the code so that I can successfully save the image from the frontend to mongodb

the schema:

```
type Mutation {
    addProfile(input: ProfileInput!): AddProfileResponse!
}

    type AddProfileResponse {
    code: Int!
    success: Boolean!
    message: String!
  }
  scalar Upload

  type Profile {
    id: ID!
    firstName: String!
    lastName: String!
    email: String!
    password: String!
    phone: String!
    image: Upload
    address: String!
    city: String!
    pincode: String!
  }

  input ProfileInput {
    firstName: String!
    lastName: String!
    email: String!
    password: String!
    phone: String!
    address: String!
    city: String!
    pin: String!
    image: Upload
  }
```

the resolver:

```
addProfile: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
      const {
        firstName,
        lastName,
        email,
        password,
        phone,
        image,
        address,
        city,
        pincode
      } = args.input;
      console.log(args);
      try {
        const new_profile = new Profile({
          firstName,
          lastName,
          email,
          password,
          phone,
          image,
          address,
          city,
          pincode
        });
        if (image) {
          console.log("image is" + image);
          const { createReadStream, filename, mimetype } = await image;
          const stream = createReadStream();
          const pathname = path.join(__dirname, `../public/images/${filename}`);
          await stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(pathname));
          console.log("pathname is" + pathname);
          // const buffer = [];
          // stream.on("data", (chunk) => buffer.push(chunk));
          // stream.on("end", async () => {
          //   const image = {
          //     data: Buffer.concat(buffer),
          //     contentType: mimetype
          //   };
          //   new_profile.image = image;
          //   try {
          //     await new_profile.save();
          //   } catch (error) {
          //     console.log(error);
          //   }
          // });
        } else {
          await new_profile.save();
          // console.log(await profile.find());
        }
        // const profile = await profile.find();
        return {
          code: 200,
          success: true,
          message: "Item added"
          // profile: profile
        };
      } catch (error) {
        return {
          code: 500,
          success: false,
          message: error
          // profile: await profile.find()
        };
      }
    },
```

frontend function:

```
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    phone: "",
    address: "",
    city: "",
    pin: "",
    image: null
  });

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(formData);

    try {
      const response = await createProfile({
        variables: {
          input: formData
        }
      });
      console.log(response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Where are you validating that your form is completely filled out? Since all your fields except image are required you'll get a 400 if any of your fields are blank.